# Google maps API getProjection() not working in V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

According to the API ref, the map object should have a getProjection
method: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Map

While loading the map in this example
should alert the x,y point, but instead
throws the value as undefined. This is the below sample code called in onload.

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    alert("projection:" + map.getProjection());
}
```

Answer (score 44):

It isn't available until the map is finished initializing.  You have to wait on the "projection_changed" event before accessing it.

```
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 8,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,"projection_changed", function() {
   alert("projection:"+map.getProjection());
 });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/om9b3cut/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "projection_changed", function() {
    console.log("projection:" + map.getProjection());
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "map.getProjection()=" + JSON.stringify(map.getProjection(), null, ' ');
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map-canvas {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```