# Shift center of google map (Error: Cannot read property 'fromLatLngToContainerPixel' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I request a route with Google Maps API and route is afterwards centered automatically because I'm useing the option "preserveViewport: false". Now I want the shift the center a little bit. So I tried it by the following code:

```
var overlay_1 = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay_1.draw = function () {};
overlay_1.setMap(map_1);

var point_1
point_1 = overlay_1.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(map_1.getCenter());
point_1.x = point_1.x + 300;
map_1.setCenter(overlay_1.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point_1));
```

When I'm starting the webpage I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromLatLngToContainerPixel'
>   of undefined

As you can see at my [Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flXjf.png), the code is working when I'm putting it into my console.

Does anybody has any idea why I'm getting the Error when it is loading my webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the `projection_changed` event to fire on the overlay before the `.getProjection` method will return a valid result.

Related question: [Why getProjection() is not working in V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191664/why-getprojection-is-not-working-in-v3)

```
var overlay_1 = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay_1.draw = function() {};
overlay_1.setMap(map_1);

var point_1;
google.maps.event.addListener(overlay_1, 'projection_changed', function() {
  point_1 = overlay_1.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(map_1.getCenter());
  point_1.x = point_1.x + 300;

  map_1.setCenter(overlay_1.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point_1));
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/14h9svhc/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map_1 = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var overlay_1 = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay_1.draw = function() {};
  overlay_1.setMap(map_1);

  var point_1;
  google.maps.event.addListener(overlay_1, 'projection_changed', function() {
    point_1 = overlay_1.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(map_1.getCenter());
    point_1.x = point_1.x + 300;
    map_1.setCenter(overlay_1.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point_1));
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: You are right, I don't get the error message anymore. But I still have a problem. As I said, I first request a Route before I want to do the shift. Please have a look to this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/14h9svhc/2/). By removing the two lines it is working:´ var waypoints_1 = processWaypoints([['-42.4008174','173.681386'],['-42.1550941','173.9284645'],['-41.6695819','174.0720845'],['-41.2905926','174.0010044'],]);
     requestRouteReisen(-43.5320544, 172.6362254, -41.0332502, 173.0192419, waypoints_1, 'blue', map_1);  ´

Comment: Please ask another question with a [mcve] that demonstrates your new problem.