# getProjection is not a function - google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I am trying to draw curved lines using google-maps-react.
In order to do this, I searched and found this question "[How to curve a Polyline in react-google-maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706222/how-to-curve-a-polyline-in-react-google-maps)". In this question, the answer refers to a sandbox project, in which such an implmentation is done.

I tried to adapt this code to work for me, but I am having problems getting the "projection" of the map, which is necessary to calculate the "point", using

```
const p1 = mapProjection.fromLatLngToPoint(pos1),
```

After searching the props and state of the map component, I found that the "getProjection" method is inside: props -> google -> maps -> Map -> prototype -> getProjection.

I tried to access it using:

```
mapProjection = {this.props.google.maps.Map.getProjection()}
```

and this results in an error "TypeError: this.props.google.maps.Map.getProjection is not a function".

Using

`mapProjection = {this.props.google.maps.Map.prototype.getProjection()}`

results in undefined

I am really stuck and I have no clue how to get around this. Can any of you point me in the right direction? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you think you could put your code in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) so we could see it? Might make it easier to figure something out.

Comment: Hard to judge without the rest of the code, but my first guess: getProjection() is called too early.  This post shows what you can do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191664/why-getprojection-is-not-working-in-v3

Answer (score 0):

The line `this.props.google.maps.Map.getProjection()` is attempting to access a method on the map instance as a one that is statically available on the Map class itself.  Since getProjection can only be invoked on an object of the Map class, you must call `getProjection()` on the map that you instantiate with `new maps.Map(myDomNode, myMapConfig);`

If you take a look at this tutorial [How to Write a Google Maps React Component](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/#the-map-container-component) you will notice that a new map instance is created in the loadMap function of the Map component and is attached to the component with `this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig);` .

At that point, `this.map` (the map instance) becomes available to any method on the Map component and you can get the projection with `var projection = this.map.getProjection();`