# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProjection' of undefined

Tags: angular, location, maps, nativescript

I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222864/get-radius-of-visible-map-in-android) because I have simple problem. Only I need to use it in Typescript Code.

In Android this code:

```
   googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                LatLngBounds bounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                LatLng northeast = bounds.northeast;
                LatLng southwest = bounds.southwest;

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "ne:"+northeast+" sw:"+southwest;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
```

I need to write in Typescript/ Nativescript code, and write like this:

```
  public  onCameraChange() {
            var bounds = this.gMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
            console.log('bounds', bounds)
            var northeast = bounds.northeast;
            console.log('northeast', northeast)
            var southwest = bounds.southwest;
            console.log('southwest', southwest)

            var context = application.android.context.getApplicationContext();
            var text = "ne:"+northeast+" sw:"+southwest;
            console.log('context,text', context,text)
        }
```

In her, show this error:

> ```
> JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProjection' of undefined
> JS: ERROR CONTEXT {
> JS:   "view": {
> JS:     "def": {
> JS:       "nodeFlags": 16793601,
> JS:       "rootNodeFlags": 1,
> JS:       "nodeMatchedQueries": 0,
> JS:       "flags": 0,
> JS:       "nodes": [
> JS:         {
> JS:           "nodeIndex": 0,
> JS:           "parent": null,
> JS:           "renderParent": null,
> JS:           "bindingIndex": 0,
> JS:           "outputIndex": 0,
> JS:           "checkIndex": 0,
> JS:           "flags": 1,
> JS:           "childFlags": 16793601,
> JS:           "directChildFlags": 16777217,
> JS:           "childMatchedQueries": 0,
> JS:           "matchedQueries": {},
> JS:           "matchedQueryIds": 0,
> JS:           "references": {},
> JS:           "ngContentIndex": null,
> JS:           "childCount": 9,
> JS:           "bindings": [],
> JS:           "bindingFlags": 0,
> JS:           "outputs": [],
> JS:           "element": {
> JS:             "ns": "",
> JS:             "name": "GridLayout",
> JS:             "attrs": [
> JS:               [
> JS:                 "",
> JS:                 "class",
> JS:                 "page"
> JS:               ]
> JS:             ],
> JS:             "template": null,
> JS:             "componentProvider": null,
> JS:             "componentView": null...
> ```

Please can you share with me any idea how to solution? I want to get API require lat,long and radius, I'm able to get lat and lng from center point but couldn't find a way to get radius .

UPDATE :

```
  public  onCameraChange(arg) {
     this.gMap = event.object.gMap;
                    var bounds = this.gMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                    console.log('bounds', bounds)
                    var northeast = bounds.northeast;
                    console.log('northeast', northeast)
                    var southwest = bounds.southwest;
                    console.log('southwest', southwest)

                    var context = application.android.context.getApplicationContext();
                    var text = "ne:"+northeast+" sw:"+southwest;
                    console.log('context,text', context,text)
                }
```

SHOW:

```
JS: bounds LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (-66.41815185001424,-63.11405181884765), northeast=lat/lng: (66.41891785546429,63.11484139412641)}
JS: northeast lat/lng: (66.41891785546429,63.11484139412641)
JS: southwest lat/lng: (-66.41815185001424,-63.11405181884765)
```

**App closed automatic**

1. How to calculate radius in this part?
2. Why my application closed?

Comment: have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191664/why-getprojection-is-not-working-in-v3 ?

Comment: Try commenting the line, find out where exactly it closes. May be the logcat in Android Studio will give detailed logs, see if you find anything related there.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import gMap and also add instance into constructor

Comment: Still you getting Cannot read property 'getProjection' of undefined

Comment: I can get `JS: bounds LatLngBounds{southwest=lat/lng: (-66.41815185001424,-63.11405181884765), northeast=lat/lng: (66.41891785546429,63.11484139412641)}`

Comment: But the question is different